# Error al obtener la fecha más vieja SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy intentando obtener el registro más viejo que se ha vendido:

```
Select *
    FROM articulos
WHERE COD_ARTICULO= '1A' AND MIN(FEC_ACTU) AND ROWNUM = 1
```

A1 son cosas del hogar (mesas, sillas, etc..)

El problema es que cuando pongo **MIN(FEC_ACTU)** para obtener el registro más viejo me dice que no es una expresión de grupo.

El motor de búsqueda es Oracle usando el lenguaje de SQL.

Por otro lado he visto que usando:

```
Select *
FROM (SELECT * FROM articulos a
      WHERE a.COD_ARTICULO= '1A' 
      order by FEC_ACTU ASC )
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Obtengo el mismo resultado que esperaba con lo del MIN(FEC_ACTU).

El problema es que como tengo que enlazar 2 tablas, he repetido la misma "ñapa" sin éxito:

```
Select *
FROM (SELECT * FROM articulos a, his_articulos b
      WHERE a.COD_ARTICULO= '1A' and a.COD_ARTICULO = b.COD_ARTICULO and b.COD_ARTICULO = '1A'
      order by FEC_ACTU ASC )
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Porque me dice que el order by del fec_actu es ambiguo, ya que existe en ambas tablas.

Entonces he decido usar:

```
 Select NOMBRE
    FROM (SELECT a.NOMBRE FROM articulos a, his_articulos b
          WHERE a.COD_ARTICULO= '1A' and a.COD_ARTICULO = b.COD_ARTICULO and b.COD_ARTICULO = '1A'
          order by a.FEC_ACTU ASC )
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Como se puede ver estoy usando el a.fec_actu y el a.nombre, es decir, se hace referencia a la tabla "a" y me saca el nombre más viejo de la tabla A, pero el problema es que el artículo más viejo está en la tabla b.

Lo que intento hacer es:
Obtener el registro más viejo de entre 2 tablas, que son iguales, pero una es la histórica de la otra y con el 1º intento del MIN me decía que no se podía y con este segundo intento al decir que los parámetros son ambiguos me saca los registros de la tabla que se defienen.

Comment: qué motor de base de datos estás usando?

Comment: pl sql developer versión 11

Comment: Si usas SQLDeveloper, el motor de base de datos debe ser Oracle entonces, ¿no? Ya tienes suficiente reputación para que sea engorroso pedirte que incluyas la información escencial en tu pregunta. Sugiero que incluyas las partes esenciales de la estructura de la tabla y un ejemplo de la salida que esperas obtener, ya que con la explicación no queda suficientemente claro.

Comment: @jachguate, Mi experiencia no está vinculada a SQL... Ya tienes toda la información y he estado haciendo más pruebas, pero sigo sin sacarlo, ¿ puedes echar un vistazo por favor ? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Si una tabla es histórica, por qué haces _inner join_ de ambas? ¿Es decir, siempre existen los mismos registros en las dos? ¿O te interesan solamente los que están en ambas?

Comment: Sobre la experiencia, no hace falta que sepas de SQL, está bien preguntar, pero ya debieras tener claro lo importante que es explicarse bien, incluyendo tirar de ejemplos, datos y código.

Comment: inner join... como ya he dicho, no tengo mucha experiencia con sql, investigaré a ver qué es, cuando un dato cambia en la tabla de articulos, por ejemplo ahora tiene el 5% de descuento, se va a la historico que quizás en ese momento tenía un 20% de descuento. Esto hace que un mismo artículo está 8934589 veces entre las 2 tablas, esto es para explicarte esa tabla, la cuestión es que entre esas 2 tablas, es sacar el registro más viejo del codigo del articulo "1A,1B" etc... y como son iguales, las columnas se llaman igual y todo eso...

Comment: @jachguate SQLDeveloper soporta distintos motores mediante jdbc.

Comment: Revisa el resultado de: `SELECT min(FEC_ACTU) FROM articulos WHERE COD_ARTICULO= '1A'`

Comment: @Sal, lo entiendo, por eso no lo afirmé. Diría que el 90% de la gente que usa SQLDeveloper lo usa para conectarse a Oracle, puede que me equivoque.

Comment: @Sal eso devuelve fecha, sí, pero no sé a qué pertenece:  SELECT min(FEC_ACTU), NOMBRE FROM ... en cuanto pongo alguna columna me saca el error de que "la función de grupo no es de grupo único" y tampoco resolvería el problema de que es la menor fecha entre las 2 tablas... gracias!!

Comment: @EduBw No es una respuesta, es para guiarte ;). Esa misma columna que agregaste al `SELECT` agrégala también al `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Las discusiones largas van en un chat. Eviten estas hileras de comentarios, por favor

Comment: @EduBw, las dos tablas tienen los mismos campos?

Comment: @Japv la de histórico creo que tiene 1 ó 2 campos más.

Comment: Lo mejor para entender mejor lo que desea realizar es que adicione a la pregunta unos cuantos datos de ejemplo y el resultado que espera obtener.